# Why does this C# code to run executables not work?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write code to detect a USB drive and check for .exe files in each of its directories. I succeeded in doing this, but now I want to run that exe file. I'm not able to do that. Why does this code not work?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        listremovable();
}

private void listremovable()
{

    foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        if (d.IsReady && d.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
            listBox1.Items.Add(d);

    }
    MessageBox.Show(drive.ToString());

    if (listBox1.Items.Count < 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("no usb");
    }

}

public void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox2.Items.Clear();
    try
    {
        DriveInfo drive = (DriveInfo)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dirinfo in drive.RootDirectory.GetDirectories())
            foreach (var file in dirinfo.GetFiles())
                if (file.Extension == ".exe")
                    listBox2.Items.Add(file);
        //MessageBox.Show(drive);

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pro = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    //string hel = Directory.GetDirectories
    MessageBox.Show(pro);
    //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pro);
}
```

Comment: Please isolate a specific code part you need help with. http://sscce.org

Answer (score 7):

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo dirinfo in drive.RootDirectory.GetDirectories())
    foreach (var file in dirinfo.GetFiles())
        if (file.Extension == ".exe")
            listBox2.Items.Add(file);
```

Ok, here you're using `dirInfo`, an instance of `DirectoryInfo`, and calling [`GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx) on it. `GetFiles()` returns an array of [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)  objects. Then, you walk through that array, and if you like what you see, you add those `FileInfo` objects to your list. So far so good.

```
string pro = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
//string hel = Directory.GetDirectories
MessageBox.Show(pro);
//System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pro);
```

This is the frustrated result of debugging without a debugger, but it looks like you tried to do this:

```
string pro = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pro);
```

It makes sense that this'd work, but it obviously doesn't. There's a mismatch between what you got out of your list, the aforementioned `FileInfo`, and what [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/53ezey2s) expects, a path to a file or application. You tried it, and you got a frenzied complaint from the latter method.

Here's what you want to do:

```
// get your FileInfo object
// (SelectedItem gives you a plain object, but we know it's a FileInfo
// cause that's what you gave it before, so we cast it)
FileInfo fi = (FileInfo)listBox2.SelectedItem;

// grab a path to the file out of the object
string path = fi.FullName;

// pass that path to the Start method
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

A couple of things that will help you here and later:

- Use the debugger. I see signs that you tried to discover what values certain objects held by printing them to a MessageBox. That works, but slows you down, and isn't always possible. Learn how to use Visual Studio's debugger. It's easy to use, very robust, and will pay you back very quickly.
- Use the documentation. MSDN's docs are pretty decent, a little sparse in places, but they'd show you immediately what [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx) produces, and what [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/53ezey2s) expects.

Comment: Downcast from `object` to `FileInfo` requires an explicit cast or else the `as` keyword.  Great explanation overall.  +1